Aligning neck with body on an electric guitar
I took apart an old Strat copy, my first guitar. It's actually quite good but it was laying around for a while and now the body seems to have swollen due to humidity. The neck pocket was always way too tight but now trying to get the neck in would damage the lower part of the pocket which is very thin if you know what I'm talking about. I will have to realign the neck and route out the neck pocket some more. Any tips how I could do that without breaking the bank? How do I make sure everything is dead center? I thought about building a jig with aluminum beams or something. I will buy a precision ruler to make sure it's dead straight but I have never built such a jig. Any tips and ideas? How would you go about it?

Why on Earth would you need to split the two in the first place? It's not something we generally do!

If the neck nearly fits you might try sanding the pocket down very carefully. A good fit is hard to achieve. Else — if you really want good results, why not take it to an electric guitar builder?

Also if the body has issues due to humidity the neck might as well. A professional will be able to check that. You might spend a lot of money and effort on tools and stuff to get a mediocre result that is not really playable because the neck is warped.

@Lazy - far easier to sand (or whatever) the neck rather than the  pocket.

Take it to the desert for a while. I’m actually only half kidding, if there is swelling from humidity maybe somehow dehumidifying it would solve the problem.

I’m with @JohnBelzaguy: put them in a semi-airtight plastic bin with a bunch of desiccant packs. You can buy desiccants on the web.

After all, if you remove wood to match this high-humidity state, what happens when the humidity goes down?

@ToddWilcox I wonder if there aren’t some specially designed ovens or kilns for gently drying out wood…

@JohnBelzaguy There are, used by guitar manufacturers and others who need to prepare wood for manufacture. But that’s before the finish goes on and I doubt they are cheap.

@JohnBelzaguy PRS calls their wood kiln "the hot room" and depending on the wood type and origin may dry their woods between 24 hours and two weeks: https://youtu.be/qObaW-O1Iu8?si=mXT2tByljwmgukUV They also have a "neck drying room" https://youtu.be/0cbKCA9M8cs?si=JlgIzBAxUusVNthQ

'The neck pocket was always way too tight' - most folk never ever take the neck off their guitars. How often have you done this, and why???

I don't see how explaining the reson why I took the neck off will help me find a flat surface for measurements. Neck is twisted. I need to measure how much and build a jig to untwist it using heat. That wasn't my question though.

The twisted neck would appear to be a far more devastating and insurmountable problem than getting it aligned to the body.

It's just very slightly twisted. If you take off the paint then moisten the wood and build a jig to untwist it it should be okay. You just heat it up and the jig forces it in an untwisted position. From there you just inlay two carbon fiber rods into the neck by routing two channels and that's it. That neck will never move again since carbon fiber enforced necks are incredibly stable. So that isn't the problem. But I need a flat surface to measure if the untwisting was succesful.

If you really must get them together again, and using a vice won't help them re-unite, it's best to fettle the end of the neck - it's more accessible than the inside of the pocket, and using 100 grit would be a good start. And easier to take the same few thou off each side. Some soap will help lubricate it all, too.

Yes but as I said the guitar has some problems anyway. I need a perfectly flat surface to make some measurements to determine if the alignment is correct. It's not just about getting the guitar neck in there. I also need a generally very flat surface to measure other stuff. I know granite that is certified flat can be bought but I don't know how much a piece that is about 1 - 1.5 meters long would cost me.

This honestly sounds like it's not a diy. A good luthier will be able to sort it, albeit at a cost - maybe more than the guitar's worth. But a visit would be my first plan, if this was my first foray into guitar mending.

@EbonyPope - you don't necessarily need a surface that is certified flat. The first few electric guitars I built needed to be taken apart, shims added, reassembled numerous times and they play amazingly well now. I'm saying you can easily tweak into final alignment.

I have some experience with electrics don't worry. Telling me to bring it to a luthier won't help since I want to do it myself. People nowadays are way too reliant on others. No wonder most boys couldn't do a simple tire change nowadays. Also I need that surface to measure several other things. Not just my guitar. It's just something I need as a reference point. "Just take it to a luthier" isn't an option and not why I posed the question in the first place.

@EbonyPope - notice I covered myself - 'if it was my first foray'! Should have mentioned this in the question?

Sure. I just need something really flat that won't cost me hundreds of dollars.

@EbonyPope - table tops are notorious (?) for being flat. They're found in many houses..!

Problem is how flat? Tabletops are often made out of wood a material that is constantly changing due to humidity etc. So deviations from perfect level are pretty common. I thought about buying a granite slab but they are pretty expensive if they are certified flat. Someone suggested a pool table. I will give that a try.

@EbonyPope - how about a kitchen work surface?

It's very warped and not very flat. It's made of wood and it swoll after some water damage. I think I'm gonna buy a slab of certified flat granite. I have seen someone offering it for 50 bucks. Not wanting to beg for an upvote but could you give my question an upvote? I'm new here.

First it's slightly twisted, now it's very warped. Honest advice - it needs more than carbon fibre, and a flat surface. And if it won't fit in the pocket, there's another problem. 'Twere me, I'd be finding a replacement neck - loads available on Ebay, etc. No upvote, yet, but no dv either - as it seems the answer can't be more than I've proffered.
